# uboot timeouts, but tftp server says transfer done- integer-folds of 512 bytes

Tags: timeout, u-boot, tftp

I am trying to download a file with uboot. 
When the filesize is 512 bytes and it integer-folds, Uboot gives timeout, but tftp server says transfer done.

TFTP Server is on Windows 7

Uboot log:

```
using FM1@DTSEC2 device
TFTP from server 192.168.1.22; our IP address is 192.168.1.21
Filename 'u-boot_p4080ds.bin'.
Load address: 0x100000
Loading: #################################################################
         #################################################################
         ########################T T T T T T T T T T
Retry count exceeded; starting again
FM2@DTSEC1 Waiting for PHY auto negotiation to complete......... TIMEOUT !
FM2@DTSEC1: No link.
FM2@DTSEC2 Waiting for PHY auto negotiation to complete......... TIMEOUT !
FM2@DTSEC2: No link.
FM2@DTSEC3 Waiting for PHY auto negotiation to complete......... TIMEOUT !
FM2@DTSEC3: No link.
FM2@DTSEC4 Waiting for PHY auto negotiation to complete......... TIMEOUT !
FM2@DTSEC4: No link.
```

Tftp server log:

```
15:48:15 INFO  TFTPServer        - Transferring file (binary): u-boot_p4080ds.bin
15:48:15 INFO  TFTPServer        - Transfer done: u-boot_p4080ds.bin
```

For example, if filesize is 1023 bytes or 1025 bytes, transfer completes successfully. However, if filesize is 1024 bytes, it fails.

What is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

In this case, the problem is the TFTP server that you are using. Try another TFTP server like SolarWind.

Comment: Can you post this as a comment and then add as an answer once it's confirmed?